# Is there any way for object detection in ios without classifying the objects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tensorflow, coreml

Purpose - To Detect an object without classifying in ios.

I have a tflite model to use in xcode but the possible ways I found are working as classifier. I tried to convert the model in CoreML too but it doesn't work properly.

Below is the code which called everytime when a frame is captured and loads the model:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Resnet50().model) else { return }
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedRequest, error) in
        guard let results = finishedRequest.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
        guard let Observation = results.first else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.label.text = "\(Observation.identifier)"
            print(Observation.confidence)
        })
    }
     guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

    // executes request
    try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: Added the code in the query.

Comment: Resnet50 is a classifier, it only works as such. If you want to do object detection, you'll need to use a different kind of model such as YOLO or SSD. You can train an object detection model for Vision using Turi Create.